# Renaming custom fields

Tags: wordpress

I found a number of plugins to rename a WP custom field and also some posts about how to do it by doing stuff directly in the database. Is it possible to achieve it more simply than that ?

Comment: Some context information would be helpful. You could, for example, tell us which software you are talking about.

Comment: Lol I'm such a nut, I'm talking about WordPress !

Answer (score 8):

To do this you can use the following SQL:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_key` = 'NEW NAME' WHERE `meta_key` = 'OLD NAME'
```

Make sure that, if you have a prefix on your tables, you update the table name "wp_postmeta" to the actual name you have.